# UITableView cells selection works correctly only if a breakpoint is set

Tags: ios, uitableview

I need to add a string and then select added row keeping all selections made before.

Due to architecture issues I have to call `refreshSelections`, which deselects at first and selects after it, twice.

At fact after adding a row all selections flashing and only the added row is selected. If I add another row all old selections will flash again leaving the new row selected.

But if I set a breakpoint in any place after first `refreshSelections` it'll work ok.

I think it's some concurrency problem but I don't know how to solve it.

```
// This is called
-(void)addString:(NSString *)text
{
    stringsList = [stringsList arrayByAddingObject:text];
    [self applyFilter:self.searchBar.text];
    // Any breakpoint after will help
    [filterSelect addStringToSelected:text];
}

- (void)applyFilter:(NSString *)filterString
{
    [filterSelect reloadData:YES];
}

- (void)refreshSelections
{
    for (NSUInteger row = 0; row < stringsList.count; ++row) {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:row inSection:0];
        [stringsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:NO];
    }

    NSIndexSet *selectedIndexes = [stringsList indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [selectedStrings containsObject:obj];
    }];

    [selectedIndexes enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [stringsTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:idx inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }];
}

- (void)reloadData:(BOOL)saveOrder
{
    stringsList = [self.dataSource stringsToDisplayInMultipleStringsSelect:self];

    [stringsTableView reloadData];
    [self refreshSelections];
}

- (void)addStringToSelected:(NSString *)string
{
    [self storeSelectedString:string];
    [self refreshSelections:1];
}
```

All of my WAT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be solved by adding a 0.1s delay before calling the function under the comment to update UI first.

```objective-c
- (void)addCustomStringControllerDelegate:(AddCustomStringController *)sender didFinishWithText:(NSString *)text
{
    if (text.length) {
        stringsList = [stringsList arrayByAddingObject:text];
        [self applyFilter:self.searchBar.text];

        double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
        dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
        dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
            [filterSelect addStringToSelected:text];
        });

        [selectedValuesTableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

But I think, it's not correct that I deselect all rows and then select rows that I need. So I've chosen the way to (de)select only rows that I should.

```objective-c
- (void)refreshSelections
{
    NSArray *selectedBefore = stringsTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows;
    NSIndexSet *toSelect = [stringsList indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        return [selectedStrings containsObject:obj];
    }];

    NSMutableArray *toDeselect = [NSMutableArray new];
    for (NSIndexPath *selected in selectedBefore) {
        if (![toSelect containsIndex:selected.row]) {
            [toDeselect addObject:selected];
        }
    }

    for (NSIndexPath *deselect in toDeselect) {
        [stringsTableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:deselect animated:NO];
    }

    [toSelect enumerateIndexesUsingBlock:^(NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        [stringsTableView selectRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:idx inSection:0] animated:NO scrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone];
    }];
}
```